# Rails 6 devise gem on existing SQL db with capitalized colum name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, devise

i'm attempting to do some tests in RoR (ruby v2.6.8, rails v6.1.5):
I want to create a devise based on an existing database with existing user table (called Account, with capitalized A). I managed to execute the first steps to migrate the columns needed by Devise but i get stuck when i try to signup:

> ```
> undefined method `email' for #<Account:0x0000000110cb34f8>
>
>
>    Did you mean?  Email
>                   Email=
>                   Email?
> ```
>
> ##### Extracted source (around line **#469**):
>
> ```rb
>    else
>        match = matched_attribute_method(method.to_s)
>        match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
>      end
>    end
>    ruby2_keywords(:method_missing) if respond_to?(:ruby2_keywords, true)
> ```

Any general suggestion how to handle this and possible future problems?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is `alias_attribute`.

That will delegate the `:email` and `:email=` methods to `:Email` and `:Email=` respectively

```
class Account
  alias_attribute :email, :Email
end
```